# Sinch Push Notifications when app offline instant messaging

Tags: sinch

How does push notifications work device is offline state? example the user closed the app and this closes the sinchClient too. I am able to send notifications however how will i pass the data onto sinchClient when it is closed and if the client starts it gets the messages auto which is not what i want since the notification can store the messages inside the database. is there a way or we have to ignore when client sends new messages which already wre sent using push, thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are passing the message itself in your Push notification to your app, you should probably save the `messageId` in your app and then compare it with any `onIncomingMessage` `messageId` and ignore that message. You can get the `messageId` from the object returned from `relayRemotePushNotification(String)` (`NotificationResult.getMessageResult().getMessageId()`) (with appropriate checks that it's a MessageResult and not a call push if you are also using calling).

Comment: Thanks, database design is already implemented this way. I was just checking if there was another way :)